# Parse the backup\restore path and filename during the backup\restore

Tags: t-sql, database-backups, database-restore

I'm writing a webapp that monitors backup and restores while they are happening.  What I've been asked to add to it was a way to show the backup\restore path and filename ***as it's happening***.
I'm able to, of course, get the command line that is running during the backup\restore so what I'd like to do is extract the path and filename from that command line.
So with my current code I am able to get this in a return by itself:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] TO DISK = N'\\nas01\sqlbackups$\ServerName\DatabaseName.bak'   WITH NOFORMAT,   INIT,   NAME = N'DatabaeName-Full Database Backup',   SKIP,   NOREWIND,   NOUNLOAD,   STATS = 10
```

What I'd like to extract from that is **\\nas01\sqlbackups$\ServerName\DatabaseName.bak**

If not extracting from the code, is there a way to grab that from another table, ***while it's currently running?***

This is the code I run to get the state of a current backup\restore:

```
SELECT r.session_id
,r.command
,CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 2), r.percent_complete) AS [Percent Complete]
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(ms, r.estimated_completion_time, GetDate()), 20) AS [ETA Completion Time]
,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.total_elapsed_time / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [Elapsed Min]
,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.total_elapsed_time / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) AS [Elapsed Hours]
,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.estimated_completion_time / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [ETA Min]
,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), r.estimated_completion_time / 1000.0 / 60.0 / 60.0) AS [ETA Hours]
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(TEXT, r.statement_start_offset / 2, CASE 
                    WHEN r.statement_end_offset = - 1
                        THEN 1000
                    ELSE (r.statement_end_offset - r.statement_start_offset) / 2
                    END)
        FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
        )) AS [TSQLCode]    
        FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r 
WHERE command IN (
    'RESTORE DATABASE'
    ,'BACKUP DATABASE'
    ,'BACKUP LOG'
    ,'RESTORE LOG'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure, but I think [Backup History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-history-and-header-information-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#BnRHistoryTables) can show you information about backup in progress. You could try, though. Otherwise, you can try to parse the command text. First remove the text prior "TO DISK", find the first and second quote and get the text between them. Use code like this:

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max) = N'BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] TO DISK = N''\\nas01\sqlbackups$\ServerName\DatabaseName.bak''   WITH NOFORMAT,   INIT,   NAME = N''DatabaeName-Full Database Backup'',   SKIP,   NOREWIND,   NOUNLOAD,   STATS = 10  '

-- Remove the text before "TO DISK"
set @cmd = SUBSTRING(@cmd, PATINDEX(N'%TO DISK%', @cmd), LEN(@cmd))
print @cmd
-- Remove the text before and including the first quote
set @cmd = SUBSTRING(@cmd, PATINDEX(N'%''%', @cmd) + 1, LEN(@cmd))
print @cmd
-- Get the text from the start to the next quote
set @cmd = SUBSTRING(@cmd, 1, PATINDEX(N'%''%', @cmd) - 1)
print @cmd
```